# Snow Leopard Permissions in Shared Folders reset on saving file

Tags: windows, mac-osx, permissions, samba, osx-snow-leopard

I have several users who access their accounts on OSX through their windows machines over samba. As soon as they update/save a file, it sets the permissions to -rwxr----- which means no other users can read the files. This affects apache user, for example, so changes to their files under their Sites directory means Apache can no longer serve the pages.

I've looked into /etc/smb.conf, /var/db/smb.conf, and /var/db/samba/smb.shares but I can't figure out how to force it to use the parent folders permissions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen when saving any file from any application?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something here: [Bug 4164 – Samba unix extensions should be turned off](http://bugs.contribs.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4164)